# Calculating math in GPS format

Tags: java, android

I'm making a Android Application to calculate Math in GPS Format.

Example:

Given

`N 48°44.(30x4) E 019°08.[(13x31)+16]`

the App calculates it, and result is:

`N 48°44.120 E 019°08.419`

Is it possible to do this?

I searched for plugins and solutions, but it's all just for math strings like as "14 + 6".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are working in Java as it is tagged in your question.

You could create a new public class for your GPS coordinates, and store the actual value of the coordinate in the lowest division, which according to your example appears to be minutes or seconds. This allows you to store the value as an int or a double with whatever precision you wish. You could then create a set of private and public methods to complete your mathematical operations and others to display your values in the appropriate fashion:

```
public class GPSCoordinate {

    private double verticalcoord;
    private double horizontalcoord;

    //Constructors
    GPSCoordinate(){
        setVertical(0);
        setHorizontal(0);
    }

    GPSCoordinate(double vert, double horiz){
        setVertical(vert);
        setHorizontal(horiz);
    }

    //Display methods
    public String verticalString(){
        return ((int)verticalcoord / 60) + "°" + (verticalcoord - ((int)verticalcoord / 60) *60);
    }

    public String horizontalString(){
        return ((int)horizontalcoord / 60) + "°" + (horizontalcoord - ((int)horizontalcoord / 60) *60);
    }

    //Setting Methods
    public void setVertical(double x){
        this.verticalcoord = x;
    }

    public void setHorizontal(double x){
        this.horizontalcoord = x;
    }

    //Math Methods
    public void addMinutesVertical(double x){
        this.verticalcoord += x;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to initiate an instance in your main code with a given GPS coordinate, and then you can call your math functions on it.

```
GPSCoordinate coord1 = new GPSCoordinate(567.23, 245);
coord1.addMinutesVertical(50);
coord1.otherMathFunction(50 * 30);
```

You will, of course, need to refine the above to make it fit your project. If this isn't helpful, please provide more specifics and I'll see if I can think of anything else that might fit what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just `substring` the whole thing and search for the expression in the brackets? Then it's just a matter of simple calculation. If I understood the question correctly. The gps data doesn't look like an ordinary expression, so you can't appy `math()` directly.

Comment: Hmm, but the Math Expressions not must be only in brackets and positions may not be the same as position in example[N 32+42°8+10.55 etc..]. But, i now get a idea how do it, i go test it.. If it not function, i reply with comment.. Thanx for reply [with you reply i got the idea...]

Comment: Yes it can differ. If you can give examples with the possibiliies I might be able to work out an example formulau for the `substr` expression.

Comment: Verry big thanx, with you post a got idea [There is also what you wrote], and its working perfectly.. Verry big thanx :)